# Stories from a grade school English textbook series, teenagers meet alien in museum get sent to space

Tags: story-identification

Please help to identify this story I only remember two of the stories but as I recall they  were in a series of English comprehension textbooks.

1) Origin Story: Children/teenagers meet alien in a museum after they get sidetracked from their school party get sent out into space and visit different worlds and their hope is to find a way back to earth.

2) Children/teenagers find themselves on a world with humanoid aliens, but on this world brain transplants are possible.

I would like to read the full arc of the story.

Answer (score 1):

You may be referring to [My Teacher is an Alien](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Teacher_Is_an_Alien). However, I am not 100% sure. This is a series for young readers, but I don't recall some of the specifics that you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for "Journey Through The Stars" by Clive Endersby. I've been searching for this story for several years and finally had a partial breakthrough on the weekend.

It was a six part story, each story in an anthology series that were read in elementary school, typically Grade 4/5/6 (two stories were read per year).

In part one, five children are taken from a Science Museum by a two-headed alien. On the first world they land, they help a group of three-meter tall, blue aliens reclaim their planet from rock-like robots that had been programmed to build space ships, but ended up taking over the planet.

After the children help to shutdown the robots, the blue aliens gift them with supplies and a space ship to try and find their way back to Earth.

The anthologies series names were, in order:

Grade 4 - Zoom Shots

Grade 4 - Flip Flops (Episode Two: The Silent Planet)

Grade 5 - Ripple Effects

Grade 5 - Time Spinners (Episode Four: The Platorian Zoo)

Grade 6 - Star Flights

Grade 6 - Sky Striders

Episode Two and Four are available via their anthologies on the Internet Archive:

https://archive.org/details/flipflops0000unse

https://archive.org/details/timespinners0000unse

I'm not certain if any of the six parts had brain transplants. I have so far been unable to find copies of the other four volumes online.

Possibly a duplicate of:

[Looking for a story about kids sent into space on an alien spaceship and are replaced by aliens who look like them](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58572/looking-for-a-story-about-kids-sent-into-space-on-an-alien-spaceship-and-are-rep)

If confirmed, we can mark as a duplicate.

Comment: This is a "me too" answer.

Comment: @Blackwood - Merely mentioning a possible title isn’t enough for an answer. An answer must *identify* a story, and mentioning the *possible* title (or indeed several possible titles) of a book that the answerer can’t find doesn’t do that. At best, they’re searching for the same book, and have some useful information; at worst, they’re searching for an entirely different book. Either way, they haven’t found it.

Comment: I've fixed the answer to identify the specific story.